# REPLACE statement with embedded IF() logic?

Tags: mysql, replace

**EDIT: This actually works fine, no idea why I thought otherwise.**

I have a prices table which includes a column `price_was` which needs to contain the highest ever value for prices.

Is it possible to do a REPLACE query which would update this if required?

The following (which is simplified and built dynamically in PHP) doesn't seem to work.

```
REPLACE prices
SET     price = 1.99,
        price_was = IF(1.99 > price_was, 1.99, price_was)
        id_product = 1
```

I'm thinking perhaps it's not possible, but would love to hear otherwise since I'm updating many records and need to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Tomalak apparently it worked fine and I thought otherwise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you posted is indeed valid, try it for yourself. I would use an UPDATE though since you're only updating one field and the REPLACE can possible over-write other column data you want left alone.

Comment: You are indeed right. I don't know why I thought it wasn't working. How bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

Try `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead:

```
INSERT INTO prices (price, price_was, id_product)
   VALUES (1.99, 1.99, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   price_was = IF(VALUES(price) > price_was, VALUES(price), price_was)
   id_product = VALUES(id_product)
```

This will do either an INSERT or an UPDATE, while the REPLACE statement does either an INSERT or a DELETE followed by an INSERT.  You are not able to reference old values in a REPLACE statement, probably because of the DELETE/INSERT semantics.  From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

> Values for all columns are taken from
>   the values specified in the REPLACE
>   statement. Any missing columns are set
>   to their default values, just as
>   happens for INSERT. **You cannot refer
>   to values from the current row and use
>   them in the new row.** If you use an
>   assignment such as SET col_name =
>   col_name + 1, the reference to the
>   column name on the right hand side is
>   treated as DEFAULT(col_name), so the
>   assignment is equivalent to SET
>   col_name = DEFAULT(col_name) + 1.

Comment: Worth noting that this assumes there is a primary key collision

Comment: @landoncz - true, as does the REPLACE statement.